# Camera doesnt move in z coordinate when player falls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with camera. The main problem is that   if player goes down camera cant follow it

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 positionOffset;
    public float smooth = 3.0f;

void Start()
{
    positionOffset = gameObject.transform.position - target.position;
}
void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(target.position.x + 
    positionOffset.x, positionOffset.y, target.position.z + positionOffset.z), Time.deltaTime 
   * smooth);
    }
}
```

Here is the link of the problem:https://youtu.be/0RCEmrw3Xho

Answer (score 0):

You missed changing the Y position with the target position. So the correct `LateUpdate()` should look like this:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(target.position.x + positionOffset.x, target.position.y + positionOffset.y, target.position.z + positionOffset.z), Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}
```